# How do I remove the unintended box shadow made from blurring background image of div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to have an image of a div blurred using the `filter: blur(<x>px)` property. What I have done is to have 3 divs. The first div, at the very back, has a box-shadow. The second div, in the middle (all in terms of z-index), has the blurred imaged. The very front div has the text.

I have somewhat achieved the effect I wanted, however, the problem is that the blurred background image sort of created a box-shadow effect around the border of the divs. What I want is to have the blurred image only on up to the borders of its div and only have the box-shadow effect from the very back div.

Example (view full page to view the div):

```css
#last_div,
#middle_div,
#front_div {
  top: 240px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 700px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

#last_div {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 60px -30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 0;
}

#middle_div {
  background-image: url("https://mattamyhomes.com/~/media/images/mattamywebsite/corp/home/heroslideshow/usa/orlando/orl_geohero_04_1600x800.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 1000px auto;
  filter: blur(30px);
  z-index: -1;
}

#front_div {
  color: white;
  background-color: transparent;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div id="last_div"></div>
  <div id="middle_div"></div>
  <div id="front_div">
    <div>This is some text</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a pseudo element inside the `#middle_div` and then apply `overflow: hidden` to the `#middle_div`, thus hiding the overflow from it's child elements.

```css
#last_div,
#middle_div,
#front_div {
  top: 240px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 700px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

#last_div {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 60px -30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 0;
}

#middle_div {
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
}

#middle_div::after {
  background-image: url("https://mattamyhomes.com/~/media/images/mattamywebsite/corp/home/heroslideshow/usa/orlando/orl_geohero_04_1600x800.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 1000px auto;
  bottom: 0;
  content: '';
  filter: blur(30px);
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#front_div {
  color: white;
  background-color: transparent;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div id="last_div"></div>
  <div id="middle_div"></div>
  <div id="front_div">
    <div>This is some text</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```